# What's the difference between "enamoured by" and "enamoured of"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

> Later, he became **enamored of** Japanese interlocking puzzles and dimensional wooden puzzles shaped in the form of an automobile or an animal.

From *Endgame: Bobby Fischer's Remarkable Rise and Fall*

I would've said "enamoured by" instead. Is there something about the word that makes it possible to interchange "of" and ""by"? Or is there some more fundamental rule that I'm not aware of?

Comment: to be enamored of something is a standard phrase.

Comment: @Lambie Odd, I would never say "enamored of."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only<sup>1</sup> difference is that the ***by*** version is relatively uncommon in both [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=became+enamored+of%2Cbecame+enamored+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=became+enamoured+of%2Cbecame+enamoured+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) English.

Other than that, there's no significance to the choice of preposition here. I'm not gonna bother checking, but I expect ***with*** is more common than ***by*** anyway (***of*** is far more common than both).

Note that it's a pretty "dated / affected" expression, so even though this *particular* use of ***of*** is somewhat "unusual"<sup>2</sup>, it's resistant to change precisely *because* when people use it today they're usually *deliberately* using somewhat "quaint" phrasing.

---

<sup>1</sup> I found this webpage claiming that *I'm enamoured **of** ferrets* means *I love ferrets*, whereas *I'm enamoured **by** ferrets* means *Ferrets love **me***. But I think that's just someone trying to "rationalise" the preposition usage - the full Oxford English Dictionary doesn't mention that possible distinction, and I couldn't find any examples in Google Books. I'd just ignore it.

<sup>2</sup> I say "unusual" because I can't think of any closely-related usages (involving synonyms / antonyms of ***enamoured***) that occur with preposition ***of***. In which context it's worth noting that a century or two ago, it wasn't unknown to be *enamoured **on** someone* (cf today's ***sweet on, hooked on, keen on,...***).

Comment: Do you think "enamoured by" would start to gain traction anytime soon bcoz of it sounding more natural to a modern native speaker? By "soon", I mean a century of course.

Comment: No, I don't. If you follow the first two links in my answer, you might think that the expression is holding its ground in AmE, despite have *massively* declined in BrE. But as I pointed out, the reality is it's an affected / antiquated "frozen form / fixed expression", so I wouldn't expect it to change. Even though that particular preposition use sounds a bit strange to the modern ear, I'm sure we'll continue to reproduce it faithfully. A bit like we still say *The lady **doth** protest too much* rather than ***does*** - it's "history".

Answer (score 1):

Being enamoured ('enamored' is the US spelling) is to be in love with or very fond of something or someone. We say, very often, 'enamoured of' something or, less often, 'enamoured with' something. Consider that you can use the verb transitively, for example 'Mary enamoured John'. This means that Mary affected John in a way that made him fall in love with her. This is not a common usage. Mostly, 'enamour' is used passively: 'John was enamoured of Mary' (John had fallen in love with Mary).

Saying that you are enamoured by something is very rare, verging on archaic, and liable to be misunderstood. If you love cats, then you’re enamoured of them. You can also say that you’re enamoured with them, but if you say you’re enamoured by cats, then you mean that the cats love you.

Comment: I did find [this webpage](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2021/09/enamored-with-or-by.html) backing up your claimed distinction between ***of*** and ***by***. But I couldn't find any examples in Google Books, and nothing in the full OED supports it. I think if learners start implementing the distinction in your final paragraph they'll usually be misunderstood.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Plenty in OED supports transitive use, mainly 17/18th centuries, but, as you say, no direct 'emamoured by' examples. Fowler 4th Ed. says 'much less common than either [of or with] is enamoured by' and asserts that choice is governed by 'a personal preference that may be influenced by age and location' and gives examples ('of', Dickens, Oxford Dictionary of National Biography,  NY Times, - 'with', Daily Telegraph, Boston Globe - 'by', Times of India)

Comment: I don't have easy access to Fowler 4th Ed. Apart from pointing out that ***by*** is far less common than ***of*** or ***with*** (and perhaps even ***on***), does Fowler explicitly say that ***by*** has a different meaning to all the other prepositions here? That seems a bit unlikely to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Fowler gives 'Orlando was enamoured by her looks and her long hair' as a quote from the _Times of India_, which seems like using the verb like 'seduce', 'attract', etc

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'One says, of a woman, فَتَنَتْهُ, meaning 'She enamoured him; or captivated his heart' (Edward William Lane, _An Arabic English Lexicon_ published 1863-1872)

Comment: But 'Orlando was enamoured by her looks and her long hair' *doesn't* mean her looks and hair were fascinated by Orlando in the same way your example cats are fascinated. I accept that (relatively rarely) ***to enamour*** does occur as a transitive verb - which would *suggest* we might "passivise" it with ***by***. But imho, we just don't. Perhaps at least partly because the preposition for the "reversed" meaning is ***so*** flexible that we could never be sure who's the object of whose affections! :)